# Does operating a web crawler/scraper use up my website bandwidth?

Tags: server, web-crawlers, bandwidth

I would like to operate a website crawler/scraper from my web server (doing so ethically of course).

What I am wondering is whether this uses my website bandwidth up? If so how badly and is it possible to minimise bandwidth usage? I am currently assigned 5000GB per month website bandwidth.

Comment: Note that I am the one doing the crawling through a PHP web crawler

Comment: i.e. download rather than upload...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that requests a resource (a.k.a. web page, image file, stylesheet, etc) from your server uses bandwidth. So crawling other sites from your server will count against your bandwidth limit.

Comment: What about if I am the one crawling other websites? Does that use up my bandwidth as well?

Comment: Yes. I misread your question and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok then, looks like I'll have to find out how much additional bandwidth costs then!!

Comment: Things to consider, if you're going to request pages from other sites more then once is to record the last modified date of the page. Then when you want to crawl it again you can get that info without downloading the page and if it hasn't changed you don't have to go and get it again saving you bandwidth.

Comment: Also, attempt to retrieve the page compressed and then uncompress it on the server. That will save bandwidth, too.